# Don't understand specific code in `if` statement

Tags: python

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []

    while i * i <= n:
        if (n % i):
            i = i + 1
        else:
            n = n // i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)

    return factors
```

Could somebody please comment on this code? I find it hard to understand.

The reason? The if statement with the modulus. I've never seen it like this. I am used to reading something past it, for example: if n % i == 0:

Thank you very much

Comment: This works due to the *trutiness* in Python: both.

Comment: `(n % i)` is zero if there `i` divides into `n` a whole number of times (no remainder). In Python zero is equivalent to `False` and all other values are equivalent to `True`. The conditional statement is satisfied if there is a remainder when dividing `n` by `i`.

Comment: Chris, thank you very much. I couldn't find it anywhere.